# Generics are not returned by webservice

Tags: java, generics, jboss

```
       Response profile(@WebParam(name = "key") String key,
        @WebParam(name = "data") HashMap<String, Object>[] dataList);
```

In webservice i have declared it as the above but its not taking the generics hashmap and its picking up List  instead of HashMap[] dataList.

```
  public Response profile(
    @WebParam(name = "key", targetNamespace = "")
    String key,
    @WebParam(name = "data", targetNamespace = "")
    List<HashMap> data);
```

Comment: Which web service lib are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Web services are described by WSDL, and therefore limited to what WSDL can describe. WSDL is cross language, cross platform, and it simply doesn't do generics. It does arrays, maps, primitive types. The idea behind WSDL is that the service can be written in Java or COBOL - it doesn't matter.

Oh: never declare parameters and return types with implementation classes unless it's actually important. Use `Map` rather than `HashMap`.